# NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "gem 'pg'":String)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I seem to be getting this error and am totally stuck anyone have any advice? I googled this error and didn't find an answer hoping someone can help
from the browser -

```
  def resolve_all
          config = configurations.dup
          config.each do |key, value|
            config[key] = resolve(value) if value
          end
          config
```

from the terminal -

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-10-06 21:19:43 -0700

NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "gem 'pg'":String):
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:150:in `resolve_all'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in `configurations='
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (29.8ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (25.3ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (54.2ms)
```

Comment: Do `Rails.logger.info configurations.inspect` and check if it's a hash

Comment: The type of `config' variable is String?

Comment: Can you show your `config/database.yml` file ? (replace your usernames, passwords and db urls)

Comment: @Abhi, Ali Sepehri.Kh, limekin I think it was something wrong with my app so I am trashing it... thank all of you for your responses I owe you guys a beer :)